# In MYSQL, is it better to have many rows or many columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, rows

In MYSQL, is it better to have many rows or many columns?
For example:
[image]

Versus:

[image]

Which one has a better performance if in the case  when we have too many attributes?

Comment: how many attributes are you talking about?. Also, your first design has a name: EAV (Entity Attribute Value). You can search about the pros and cons of it

Comment: I mean, database design is more about making sure you have the right amount of things as opposed to more of one than the other. Make sure you have ONLY the columns you need, and make sure you use many => one if need be rather than doing hundreds of rows.

Comment: The first is in many cases considered an antipattern; and has very limited applicability outside of "tagging" data.

Comment: As long as the attributes are in a 1:1 relationship to the object you should model them as columns.

Comment: There are many use cases where EAV seems to be the only way with mysql. I'd be loathe to program in that environment tho

Comment: @Drew, I see you are making good use of your hammer ... :)

Comment: Neither.  Age is a calculated value.  Either store the birth date or associate the age with another date, such as record created.  I would also have a relationship to a country table.

Comment: @Rahul in another 130 points for you I hope you do too :p Speaking of which perhaps I should upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the *Second* one. All those *Attributes* should go in a separate column else there is no point i storing them in RDBMS ... you can rather store them in text file as well

Comment: I think you mean the second, right?

Comment: Yes Yes ... second one ... big butt mistake